# JQuery, bind same function to 3 different textboxs' keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind

I have 3 textboxes, and on the `keyup` event for all 3, I want to call the same function?

In the below code, I am tring to bind `keyup` event to `CalculateTotalOnKeyUpEvent` function to a textbox named `compensation`, but it doesn't work:

```
$("#compensation").bind("keyup", CalculateTotalOnKeyUpEvent(keyupEvent));

function CalculateTotalOnKeyUpEvent(keyupEvent) {
  var keyCode = keyupEvent.keyCode;
  if (KeyStrokeAllowdToCalculateRefund(keyCode)) {
    CalculateTotalRefund();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need do like this:

```
// Edit according to request in the comment: 
// in order to select more than one element,
// you need to specify comma separated ids.
// Also, maybe you need to consider to use a CSS class for the selected elements,
// then it could be just $(".className")
$("#element1, #element2, ....").bind("keyup", CalculateTotalOnKeyUpEvent);
```

You need to pass the function as a parameter, you do not need to pass the function as it was declared.

Comment: probably should illuminate on how to get all three textboxes though.

Comment: You, right, I just didn't want to do it, since there was an answers after me which pointed that out.

Comment: i tried this 
$("#compensation","#adminFee", "#reimbursement").bind("keyup",CalculateTotalOnKeyUpEvent);
and its not working

Comment: You doesn't do it correct. Look at mine example. It's only one string and id's separated by commas within and not several string separated by commas.

Comment: @Artem you should replace 'element3' for '#element3' ;-) There is no html element <element3 /> hahaha :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#txt1, #txt2, #txt3").keyup(fn);
```

Answer (score 2):

or just give all 3 text boxes the same class and you good to go

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `CalculateTotalOnKeyUpEvent` immediately, not passing it as an argument. Try this:

```
$("#compensation").bind("keyup",CalculateTotalOnKeyUpEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#compensation").bind("keyup",CalculateTotalOnKeyUpEvent(keyupEvent));
```

When you write CalculateTotalOnKeyUpEvent(keyUpEvent) [notice the () after function name],  you are executing the CalculateTotalOnKeyUpEvent and assigning the result of the function to the key up event.

You should do something like,

```
$('#compensation, #otherId1, #otherId2')
    .bind('keyup', CalculateTotalOnKeyUpEvent);
```

Where 'otherId1' and 'otherId2' are the ids of two more textboxes.